# Auto update datagridview in another project

Tags: c#

In C# I would like to take TWO different projects of windows form application and inserting record in one exe i.e one form and automatic shows the inserted data into another form just like refresh, but I will not using any control like Button Refresh, update.

Comment: The topic you need to dive into is called IPC. In your case, I would consider creating a web application with ASP.NET MVC or similar rather than winforms.

Comment: But requirement is for windows application Thanks!

Comment: @Ram You still need IPC. You could search for 'Shared Memory', 'Pipes', socket-communication,...

Answer (score 0):

You have many options to solve your problem.

1) Either use a database, when the 1st app inserts into it, the 2nd app periodically looks for new records in the database, and displays them.

2) Or use a file, in the same way. The first app writes into it, and the second app reads the file periodically and display the rows.

You may need to use a Timer for this purpose.